# remove backslash from display of string(gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the list

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
exampleList.add("aaa");
exampleList.add("bbb");
exampleList.add("ccc");

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("test", gson.toJson(exampleList));
```

And  jsonObject is  {"test":"[\"aaa\",\"bbb\",\"ccc\"]"}

but i need get following
{"test":["aaa","bbb","ccc"]}

What the way to do this?

replaceAll in several ways is not solving this problem

Comment: as one of many ways       jsonObject.addProperty("test", gson.toJson(exampleList).replace("\\",""));

but this does not work, and in common sence - string not contains backslash, this is problem of display(and my http(post) request which i try do)

Comment: @rakeshkr  no,  please don't use replaceAll, try to understand what is wrong

Comment: sonObject.addProperty("test", exampleList) - in this case i need string value this backslahes

Answer (score 5):

You're adding a key-value mapping `String -> String`, that is why the quotes are escaped (in fact your value is the string representation of the list given by the `toString()` method). If you want a mapping `String -> Array`, you need to convert the list as a `JsonArray` and add it as a property.

```
jsonObject.add("test", gson.toJsonTree(exampleList, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix Gson and JsonObject,

1) if you need {"test":["aaa","bbb","ccc"]} using GSON you should define

```
public class MyJsonContainer {
   List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
   ...
   // getter and setter
}
```

and use

```
List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
exampleList.add("aaa");
exampleList.add("bbb");
exampleList.add("ccc");
MyJsonContainer jsonContainer = new MyJsonContainer();
jsonContainer.setTest(exampleList);
String json = gson.toJson(jsonContainer); // this json has {"test":["aaa","bbb","ccc"]}
```

2) if you need {"test":["aaa","bbb","ccc"]} using JsonObject you should just add

```
List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
exampleList.add("aaa");
exampleList.add("bbb");
exampleList.add("ccc");

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("test", exampleList);
```

But never try to mix Gson and JsonObject, because jsonObject.addProperty("test", text) does not allowed to add text as json and allways escaped this text.

Comment: You got a good point Viacheslav, but the code proposed -> 

    jsonObject.addProperty("test", exampleList);

Gives an error -> 

    The method addProperty(String, String) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>). The solution for this error is Gson().toJsonTree(object)

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Use this for remove `\` from string of object.